# How to make one of the filter functions conditional in a reactive function for a shiny flexdashboard?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a dataset and am building a shiny flexdashboard with multiple user inputs which filter the data down to a subset. I am struggling with just one of the filters, where if the user chooses 'ALL' in `selectInput`, I want that filter function not to do anything and just return the data as is. Below is one of my attempts:

````
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
...
qry <- read_file("some_query.sql")
Data_df  <- con %>% tbl(sql(qry)) %>% collect()
doctors_to_choose <- unique(pull(Data_df, 'Doctor')) %>%append('ALL')


Column {data-width=200 .sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
checkboxGroupInput("drug_classes",
  label = "Choose the classes of drugs",
  choices = c("II", "III", "IV", "V"),
  selected = c("V"),
)


selectInput(
  inputId="chosen_doctor",
  label="Choose Doctor",
  choices=doctors_to_choose,
  selected = "ALL",
  multiple = FALSE,
  size = NULL
)


show_data_df <- reactive({
  Data_df %>% 
filter(`Drug Class` %in% input$drug_classes) %>%
 {if (input$chosen_doctor != "ALL") filter(Doctor == input$chosen_doctor ) 
else filter(`Drug Class` %in% input$drug_classes) }
} )
```
````

I tried to use an if-else statement as above but failed.  because In the original code, I have a long list of filters applied so ideally I would like to use something that does not require me to retype all the previous filters/actions like I did in the else part above.

Comment: Put your `if` statement around the `filter` in your `reactive` And use it to create a temporary dataset that becomes the return value of the `reactive`. Eg `if (input$Chosen_doctor != “ALL”) { df <- data_df %>% filter(…)} else {…}; if (…) { …}; …; return(df)`.

Comment: Also, note than you can get your input widget to return a “default” no filter value by supplying it with a named list of values, one of which is `””`. This becomes the default. See the online doc for more details.

Comment: @Limey I am guessing by `””` you meant `""`. I read the documentation for select list input control for shiny and I see it is mentioned as a default placeholder. I went ahead and tried it anyway and it did not work as I wanted, (still went ahead and tried to filter with the value `""`. What I wanted it to do was to not filter at all or make that filter action ineffective just for that choice. This did not seem to do it unless I was supposed to change the filter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `purrr::when` to apply a `case_when` like statement within the pipe logic for `data.frame`s:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

Data_df %>% 
  filter(`Drug Class` %in% input$drug_classes) %>% 
  when(input$chosen_doctor != "ALL" ~ filter(., Doctor == input$chosen_doctor),
       TRUE                         ~ filter(., `Drug Class` %in% input$drug_classes))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was wondering if there is a way of doing this without having to repeat the entire pipe chain in my code. I guess not. Your code does do what I was trying to do, thank you very much so I will accept it.

Comment: Is there any point to putting the `filter(., \`Drug Class\` %in% input$drug_classes)` in the second part of the when function. That is a repeat of the filtering that was done before it was passed to the when function so could we not just put `.` there instead? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

@TimTeaFan has given you a very good answer.  I am not suggesting you should change your acceptance of his answer.

In response to your question in comment about placeholders, here's a demonstration of the technqiue.  I've used Shiny rather than flexdashboard because it's easier to see changes in action, but the principle will carry over into dashboard directly.  Also, because I don't have access to your input data, I've used `mtcars` as a data source.

The method I've demonstrated works for *any* number of potential filters without the need to retype any of the filter code.

And to answer your direct question: yes, I did mean `""`.  That was something I didn't notice when using an unfamiliar keyboard.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

cylChoices <- c("", sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
names(cylChoices) <- c("- All -", sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
gearChoices <- c("", sort(unique(mtcars$gear)))
names(gearChoices) <- c("- All -", sort(unique(mtcars$gear)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "cylCount", 
    "Cylinder count:", 
    multiple=TRUE,
    selected="- All -",
    choices=cylChoices
  ),
  selectInput(
    "gearCount", 
    "Gear count:", 
    multiple=TRUE,
    selected="- All -",
    choices=gearChoices
  ),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filteredData <- reactive({
    df <- as_tibble(mtcars, rownames="Model")
    if (!is.null(input$gearCount)) df <- df %>% filter(gear %in% input$gearCount)
    if (!is.null(input$cylCount)) df <- df %>% filter(cyl %in% input$cylCount)
    df
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({ filteredData() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Any idea what could cause the dashboard to display nothing when `--All--` is chosen for one of the fields. (`SiteNM`.) I simply adapted your code to my needs. The only other difference being that your code built a shiny app and me shiny flexdashboard. `show_data_df <- reactive({
  
  Data_df <- Data_df %>% filter(\`DrugClass\` %in% input$drug_classes)
  Data_df <- Data_df %>% filter(FillsNBR >= input$number_of_fills)
  if (!is.null(input$chosen_site)) Data_df <- Data_df %>% filter(SiteNM == input$chosen_site) 
  
} )`